# Taking the average of date times

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code which includes two columns where the first column is the time that a process is started and the second column is the time that the process is finished. I changed the type of these columns from str to dataset by the following code. Then I defined a new column named 'Duration' that shows the differences between start and finish time.

```
import pandas as pd
dta['Start_Time']=pd.to_datetime(dta['Start_Time'])
dta['Finish_Time']=pd.to_datetime(dta['Finish_Time'])
dta['Duration'] = example_df['Finish_Time']-example_df['Start_Time']
```

I need to calculate the average amount of time that it took the process to be finished. For example if I have three starting and ending date

> ((2006-06-02 9:10:00+00:00- 2006-06-02 9:00:00+00:00)+(2006-06-04 9:52:00+00:00-2006-06-04 8:52:00+00:00)+(2006-06-07 9:02:00+00:00-2006-06-07 8:54:00+00:00))/3 = 26 minutes.

I tried the following code:

```
dta['Duration'].mean()
```

However, I got the following error:

> No numeric types to aggregate

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: Times in my dataset are like this: 2019-06-16 08:14:31+00:00

Comment: I tried the code you're running and I'm getting a result: `Timedelta('0 days 00:26:00')`. Are you able to do `example_df.to_dict()` please?

Comment: The problem is that start and finish times columns are not timestamp in my data. I just modified my question to make sure that now the problem is explained more clear

Comment: I tried the same, looks like you have some trouble with parsing the `Start Time` and `Finish Time` as timestamps. If you can provide a sample dataset in raw format we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dta['Duration'] = example_df['Finish_Time']-example_df['Start_Time'].astype('timedelta64[D]')
# D denotes days. Possible values: (‘Y’, ‘M’, ‘W’, ‘D’, ‘days’, ‘day’, ‘hours’, hour’, ‘hr’, ‘h’, ‘m’, ‘minute’, ‘min’, ‘minutes’, ‘T’, ‘S’, ‘seconds’, ‘sec’, ‘second’, ‘ms’, ‘milliseconds’, ‘millisecond’, ‘milli’, ‘millis’, ‘L’, ‘us’, ‘microseconds’, ‘microsecond’, ‘micro’, ‘micros’, ‘U’, ‘ns’, ‘nanoseconds’, ‘nano’, ‘nanos’, ‘nanosecond’, ‘N’)
dta['Duration'].mean()
```